# Hide all RadToolTips on page upon OnItemDragStarted from RadListView

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have a number of `RadToolTips` within 2 `RadListView`s on a page.

When I drag one element from one `RadListView` to the other `RadListView` the `RadToolTip`s keep showing up on mouse hover (as expected on hover).

How can I in JavaScript disable all the `RadToolTips` on the page when `OnItemDragStarted` client event for `RadListView`. Thus stopping the `RadToolTips` from showing up upon hover only when I'm dragging an element from one `RadListView` to another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to disable all the RadToolTips from all items on the page, or just for your 2 list views that you're dragging/dropping from?

Comment: when dragging from the left RadListView to the right RadListView i need to disable the right RadListView's RadToolTips (the one im hovering over or all within this RadViewList), on mouse hover they show, and its hard to see where the user is dropping the draggable item.

Comment: could you provide some code, do you have a <telerk:RadToolTip..> defined on your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a RadToolTip on your page, and a couple of list views you could try using a global js variable, and the onDrag and onDrop settings to toggle that variable.  Your RadToolTip could use that variable on the beforeShow to decide if it should show a tool tip or not.. wrote up a small sample for you (not complete)

```
//JS
var showToolTips = true;

function dragStarted(sender,args) {
        showToolTips = false;
}
function dragFinished(sender,args){
        showToolTips = true;
}

function canShowToolTips(sender,args) 
{
        args.set_cancel(showToolTips);
}

//.NET
    <telerik:RadListView ID="radListView1" runat="server">
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnItemDragStarted="dragStarted" OnItemDropped="dragFinished" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadListView>
    <telerik:RadListView ID="radListView2" runat="server">
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnItemDragStarted="dragStarted" OnItemDropped="dragFinished" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadListView>
    <telerik:RadToolTip OnClientBeforeShow="canShowToolTips" runat="server" ID="rdToolTip1"></telerik:RadToolTip>
```

Comment: Cheers Brian but set_cancel is not a api property od RadToolTip - it errors on set_cancel.

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. args.set_cancel not sender.set_cancel :)